# The suitable way for avoiding static method (in Util class maybe) which use for updating UI

Tags: android, design-patterns, static-methods

I'm beginner in Android, I read and see if use the static method in Util class for updating UI is not good for unit test. How do I avoid it in suitable way for maintaining code and unit test ?

Example:

```
class ActivityA {
    private View view;
    private MyListener myListener;
    public void methodB() {
        Util.callLogicB(this, view, myListener);
    }
}

class ActivityB {
    private View view;
    private MyListener myListener;
    public void methodC() {
        Util.callLogicB(this, view, myListener);
    }
}

class Util {
    public static void callLogicB(Context context, View view, MyListener listener) {
    // do something with view
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think the best way to implement this is to completely disconnect your views (your activity) from your logic class. This can be done using an **interface**.

Look at the code below to understand how an interface works. I created a mainActivity with a textView as a layout. The class LogicWithTextUpdate I created is capable of updating a textView inside your mainActivity **without a direct reference to it**.

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements MyViewListener {
    //Your logic class, that is capable of updating a textview
    LogicWithTextUpdate logicWithTextUpdate;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        //This is just to create a layout (with a textview inside)
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        //This creates the class using constructor (and set listener)
        logicWithTextUpdate = new LogicWithTextUpdate(this);

        //Update or execute your logic. This will update textview using interface MyViewListener (onUpdateTextListener)
        //This can be executed using a button (Onclick...)
        logicWithTextUpdate.doSomeLogic(2);
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpdateTextListener(String text) {
        //Only here code runs inside your activity class
        TextView textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView);
        textView.setText(text);
    }
}
```

As you can see. MainActivity will update textview using a "listener" onUpdateTextListener. This is described inside a interface class:

```
public interface MyViewListener {
    //to be implemented inside your mainActivity
    public void onUpdateTextListener(String text);
}
```

Now I can implement a class that can do some logic and **trigger the listener**:

```
public class LogicWithTextUpdate {
    MyViewListener myViewListener;

    //Constructor here is used to set myViewListener (but you can use a setter like setMyViewListener)
    public LogicWithTextUpdate(MyViewListener myViewListener) {
        this.myViewListener = myViewListener;
    }

    public void doSomeLogic(int a) {
        //Some logic
        a = a * 2;
        a = a + 1;

        //Update text using listener. This will update mainActivity, because it is implementing MyViewListener
        myViewListener.onUpdateTextListener(String.valueOf(a));
    }
}
```

The method doSomeLogic is executed from your activity, but the logic is inside the class. After the logic is executed it **triggers myViewListener.onUpdateTextListener that executes onUpdateTextListener** inside your activity.

Everything is **disconnect**. You can change your views without any modification in LogicWithTextUpdate, or **change the logic without modifications in Actitivy**. Always a good practice.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, it seems good practice. However I see we have to instantiate logicWithTextUpdate = new LogicWithTextUpdate(this);  in every activity or fragment which need to use this logic ? Does it make the app performance down ?

Comment: This is a logic with a text update. So I guess you will always have something to update. If you want, you can create a setListener(MyViewListener myViewListener). If listernet is not set, than it is not executed. The constructor will not have (this) option.

Comment: :( sorry for my bad english

Comment: My question is why always create new object for creating same logic for every activity. Even when we call setListener, we have to create it in the calling method to call setListener. Is there anywhere in new architecture or design pattern to put this logic, and when we need we only call it ?

Comment: You will have to do that anyway. Check your class: public static void callLogicB, for instance, it has context as a parameter, you will pass context and reference something from another view inside your class. If a lot of fragments or activities use your class, they all have to be the same (same ID and same views) to be referenced.

Comment: Using an interface, all activities will instantiate your class and implement a listener. This is the way everything is done in Android Java. Take a look at the Button class listeners: OnClick, OnTouch, OnAnything else... Disconnect logic classes from views classes: that's the key in my opinion...

Comment: :) thanks for your answer, you make me remember the way of Button class listeners do.

Answer (score 2):

AFAIK, it's good practice to exclusively use Utility classes for static, helper methods that generally return primitive and reference data as opposed to updating UI which should be done only in Activities. For instance, a sample Utility class would involve a series of methods such as:

- A method that builds a URL object out of a HTTP request URL in String format
- A method that returns readable JSON data after successfully connecting to the HTTP server
- A method that extracts the JSON data and stores them in a returnable ArrayList
- A public, static method that invoked all of the above to ultimately return the ArrayList of data to an Activity via its background thread to later render UI via its UI thread

Comment: Thanks for your answer, however when I want to reuse some code which affect UI. For example: create and show same alert dialog for displaying same error. How can I reuse it for avoiding write many times ?

Comment: @HienNguyen AlertDialogs are different since they're not views so you could display them in your Utility class if need be. Just simply create an instance of Utils in an Activity by passing in the Activity's context to the constructor to ultimately display an AlertDialog in one of Utils' methods... and yes, you'll need to create instances of Utils in Activities if you want to avoid the static approach.

Answer (score 1):

Static class is bad for unit testing, because you can not mock or stub it. But static utility class could be very useful approach. I'd suggest you to wrap some interface reference into static utility class, you'll still have the same utility class signature, but it allows you to change behaviour of utility classes for tests or other purpose:

```
final class Util {
    static IUtil util = new DefaultUtil();
    private Util() {}

    public static void callLogicB(Context context, View view, MyListener listener) {
        util.callLogicB(context, view, listener);
    }

}


interface IUtil {
    public void callLogicB(Context context, View view, MyListener listener);
}

final class DefaultUtil implemets IUtil {
    @Override
    public void callLogicB(Context context, View view, MyListener listener) {
    // do something with view
    }
}

final class TestUtil implemets IUtil {
    @Override
    public void callLogicB(Context context, View view, MyListener listener) {
    //your test logic
    }
}

@Before
void setUp() {
    Util.util = new TestUtil();
}
```